# Is pypdf2 the same as PyPDF2?

Tags: pip, pypi, pypdf, python-packaging

Using *pip* I installed *PyPDF2*. The first time i used all lowercase so `pip install pypdf2`, an application was downloaded and installed. However then I realized (by further reading the tutorial) that it is case sensitive. So then I installed *PyPDF2* again in correct format. My questions would be:

- What did I install when I did `pip install pypdf2`?
- Is it the same program, or is it something else?
- And if it is something else how can I check what I installed?
- Could it be malware?

Comment: What about checking what you have in your installed packages ? Those are just files on your filesystem you know ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is the same.** Package names are case insensitive.

Also, You can use `pip freeze` to check what packages you have installed. It will give you the full list of packages which you have installed.

And last one - **You can relax.** **It isn't malware.**

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same:

> Comparison of project names is case insensitive

https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#name